# Google Adsense ads are sometimes displayed, sometimes not

Tags: ads, adsense

We have an application developed with VueJS. Ads displayed with the Google Adsense code we use in our application sometimes do not work properly. Sometimes advertisements are displayed and sometimes not. When we looked at the source code of the site, we saw that the ad was always loaded into the Iframe, but the inside of the ad was sometimes empty. Sometimes the ad starts to appear when we refresh the same page. We observed that there was an inconsistent situation. Does anyone have any previous experience or knowledge on this subject? I would appreciate it if you could help. Thank you so much.

**You can check the ads on the following link.** https://app.senpai.gg/lol/videos/

Answer (score 6):

Checked your website and always got ads. I think what you see is sometimes AdSense doesn't return any ads. There are no guarantees that ads will be filled 100% of times. Depending on country, user, website, time of day AdSense might not find appropriate ad sometime.

Comment: Hi Mikita,
Thank you very much for your detailed answer..